# Mutate a particular row, e.g. format as %?

Tags: r

Suppose I'm starting with a dataframe like this:

```
blah <- data.frame(
  lets = letters[1:6],
  rowname = letters[24:26],
  nums = 1:6
) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = lets, values_from = nums) %>% 
  replace(is.na(.), 0) %>% 
  column_to_rownames('rowname')
```

Looks like:

```
blah
  a b c d e f
x 1 0 0 4 0 0
y 0 2 0 0 5 0
z 0 0 3 0 0 6
```

I want to make row y formatted as a %. I'm guessing this isn't possible since dataframes are lists of vectors. Am I correct or can this actually be done?

Comment: What does `formatted as a %` mean? Can you show your desired result?

Comment: In the example above row y, currently `c(0,2,0,0,5,0)` would then be `c(0%, 200%, 0%,0%, 500%, 0%)`

Comment: You cannot create rows that have a different class than other rows. You should think about creating a print method that will output the results in hte format you wnat but leave the data in its original form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you want this?

```r
library(tidyverse, warn.conflicts = F)
data.frame(
  lets = letters[1:6],
  rowname = letters[24:26],
  nums = 1:6
) %>% mutate(nums = ifelse(rowname == 'y', scales::percent(nums), nums)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = lets, values_from = nums, values_fill = '0') %>% 
  column_to_rownames('rowname')
#>   a    b c d    e f
#> x 1    0 0 4    0 0
#> y 0 200% 0 0 500% 0
#> z 0    0 3 0    0 6
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: I get "Error in values_fill[[value]] : subscript out of bounds"

Comment: But updating to current version of pkg:tidyr retruns a dataframe with all columns of class character.

Comment: Not just the columns with % but the entire dataframe.

Comment: My point exactly. Read my other comments.

Comment: @IRTFM, I am unable to understand your point, yet.  Is it possible to retain only 1 value of a vector as character and other numeric?

Comment: No. It is not possible in an atomic vector. It would only be in a list. The situation in these case is different. Rows in dataframes are not vectors of any sort.

Comment: @IRTFM, pardon me I first mistook you as OP.  But converting to list will again not serve the purpose of calculations, if any.  So is there a method, where other numerics are not converted to charcters

Comment: You might try with a tibble. They are better at including lists as columns than are dataframes.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
blah[2,] <- sprintf("%0.0f%%", blah[2,]*100)
```

Comment: Is there a way to nintegrate this into a dplyr chain, e.g. in my code above when I define blah, is there a way to add right after %>% <your suggestion to format the desired row>

Comment: The other answer provide the `%>%` solution by transposing the whole dataframe.

Comment: `blah %>% "["(.,2,TRUE) %>%  "*"(.,100) %>% sprintf( fmt="%0.0f%%")`

Comment: @IRTFM Thanks a lot. But it only returns the second row. I think the  his desired  result is the final `blah` after the chain operation.

Comment: If you wanted to change the row to all class character then it requires that the entire dataframe would be character. That seems very awkward. I think a reporting strategy that leaves the data intact is much more sensible.

Answer (score 1):

Using `glue`

```
blah['y',] <- glue::glue("{blah['y',] * 100}%")
blah
   a    b  c  d    e  f
x  1    0  0  4    0  0
y 0% 200% 0% 0% 500% 0%
z  0    0  3  0    0  6
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)

t(blah) %>% as.data.frame() %>% mutate(y = str_c(y*100,'%')) %>% t()
  a    b      c    d    e      f   
x "1"  "0"    "0"  "4"  "0"    "0" 
y "0%" "200%" "0%" "0%" "500%" "0%"
z "0"  "0"    "3"  "0"  "0"    "6"
```